# How to add attribute '_meta' to an object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-voting

I'm trying to add the django-voting app to my project. I don't know how to use it in my templates, so I'm adding a new template tags for voting up or down when an user click in buttons. I don't know if there's a well form to do it.

My problem is with these kind of line in the template tag:

```
obj = Place.objects.filter(id=object_id)
Vote.objects.record_vote(obj, self.user, +1)
```

django print:

```
Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'Place' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

How I can add the attribute _meta my object 'Place'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `obj` here is not actually an object, but a queryset with one element. You should use `get` instead of `filter`, as `get` actually returns a model instance.

```
obj = Place.objects.get(id=object_id)
```