# Django image-cropping - 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, image, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am using django-image-cropping: https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping

What I am trying to achieve is simple crop by the manual. I am using 1.7.1 Django version.

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
file = models.ImageField('File', upload_to='dependencies/images/photos/')
gallery = models.ForeignKey('Gallery', related_name='images', blank=True, null=True)
cropping = ImageRatioField('file', '370x267', size_warning=True)
```

views.py

```
def photos(request):
photos = Image.objects.all()
return render_to_response('photos.html', {'photos':photos}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template

```
{% load cropping %}
{% for photo in photos %}
    <img src="{% cropped_thumbnail image "cropping" %}" border="0">
{% endfor %}
```

error

```
AttributeError at /photos/
'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
Exception Location:
/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/image_cropping/templatetags/cropping.py in cropped_thumbnail, line 16
Python Executable:
/venv/bin/python
```

[image: Template tage error]

I researched this error and found this:

[How to add attribute '_meta' to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532025/how-to-add-attribute-meta-to-an-object)

When I changed the views.py for 1 element with

```
'Test.objects.get()'
```

not

```
'Test.objects.all()'

 test = Test.objects.get(title='test')
```

to test it out it cropped perfectly.

But if I want to crop all in the Image model and use the 'for loop' I have this error.

To help you more here is the part on the line 16:

cropping.py

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def cropped_thumbnail(context, instance, ratiofieldname, **kwargs):
'''
Syntax:
{% cropped_thumbnail instancename "ratiofieldname"
    [scale=0.1|width=100|height=200|max_size="100x200"] [upscale=True] %}
'''

ratiofield = instance._meta.get_field(ratiofieldname)
image = getattr(instance, ratiofield.image_field)  # get imagefield
if ratiofield.image_fk_field:  # image is ForeignKey
    # get the imagefield
    image = getattr(image, ratiofield.image_fk_field)
```

Please help,
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass `image` to the tag but the variable containing your image model is `photo`. Change the variable name used.

Comment: Thank you, saved my day I read the code so many times, of course, thank you :))))