# Django foreign key not working for One-To-Many relationship

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm trying to write a query that when an artist id is searched, that artist's info and all of their pieces are the result, basically a join query between `Artist` and `ArtistPiece`

```python
#models.py
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class ArtistPiece(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    piece_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

```python
#views.py
from .models import Artist, ArtistPiece

class EditArtistViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def edit(self,request,artist_id):
        artist = Artist.objects.select_related().get(pk=artist_id)
        data = model_to_dict(artist)
        return render(
            request, 'ArtistInfo/edit.html', {
                'editing': 'true',
                'edit_data': json.dumps(data),
            }) 

    def submit_edit(self,request):
        return render(request, 'ArtistInfo/edit.html')
```

The above works, but it doesn't select any of the data from the ArtistPiece model, despite the primary key. Then after reading [this post](https://timmyomahony.com/blog/misconceptions-select_related-in-django/) about using `select_related` I realized that rather than looking up the artist, I'd have to look up ArtistPiece by the foreign_key, and use select_related to find the info about the artist.

I then tried this

```
def edit(self, request, artist_id):
    artist = ArtistPiece.objects.get()
    data = model_to_dict(artist)
```

Which resulted in the following error `get()` returned more than one ArtistPiece -- it returned 5!. Searching, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063748/django-get-returned-more-than-one-topic) which states that I need to use filter rather than get. I then tried this

```
def edit(self, request, artist_id):
    artist = ArtistPiece.objects.select_related('artist').filter(artist=artist_id)
    data = model_to_dict(artist)
```

Which gave the following error `'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'`. I tried searching for this error and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532025/how-to-add-attribute-meta-to-an-object) which basically suggests to use get, which seems to go against everything else I found.

To summarize, I just want to select an artist and their pieces but I can't seem to figure out how.

**Edit - I tried a few things and made some progress, but it's still not working correctly**

Just to be clear I'm trying to write a query that will look up an artist by their id, and the result will be the artist's info and the artist's pieces. I can query and retrieve the `Artist` model based on an artist_id or the `ArtistPiece` model, but not one query that will return both `Artist` and all of the `ArtistPiece` entries associated to that artist.

Adding `related_name='pieces'`to my model as @bignose has suggested, I then tried `artist = Artist.objects.select_related('pieces').filter(pk=artist_id)` but that still gave the no attribute.... error above. I then changed `data = model_to_dict(artist)` to `data = [model_to_dict(a) for a in artist]` and it worked, however the data was only the artist and nothing from the `ArtistPiece` model.

Instead of querying the `Artist` model I instead tried to query the `ArtistPiece` model as such: `artist = ArtistPiece.objects.select_related('artist').filter(artist=artist_id)`, but then only the artist's pieces were returned and no info from the `Artist` model.

Comment: I've modified the name of `ArtistPiece` to be singular; the name should reflect the fact that each instance represents *one* of those.

Answer (score 0):

`model_to_dict` accepts single model object, but your are passing into that the object of `QuerySet` type (which is quite similar to list). To get the list of dicts all the objects, you need to explicitly call `model_to_dict` on each model object like:

```
data = [model_to_dict(a) for a in artist]
```

Better way is to use [`QuerySet.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) as:

```
data = artist.values()
```

As per the [`Queryset.Values()` document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values):

> Returns a QuerySet that returns dictionaries, rather than model instances, when used as an iterable.
>
> Each of those dictionaries represents an object, with the keys corresponding to the attribute names of model objects.

Also take a look at [`Serializer`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) class. I think it will be useful for you.

Comment: That partially works. I can query either the `Artist` model or the `ArtistPiece` model, but I can't seem to get a "combined" query using the foreign key. I edited my post above to show the changes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `ForeignKey` field type automatically also sets an attribute on the foreign model; in your case, `Artist.artistpieces_set`.

```python
favourite_artist = Artist.objects.get(pk="foo")  # However you get an Artist instance.
favourite_artist.artistpieces_set  # Is a QuerySet of all the ArtistPiece instances that reference this instance.

# Because it's a QuerySet, you can iterate it, filter it, etc.
for piece in favourite_artist.artistpieces_set.all():
    put_in_exhibition(piece)
```

Thus, when you get an `Artist` instance, it automatically has an attribute that is a `QueryManager` for the `ArtistPiece` instances referencing that `Artist`.

This is good because it means the foreign key relationship is defined in one place, but it is also accessible from the other end.

See the documentation for “[Following relationships “backwards”](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)” for how to use these features.

Comment: When I try this `favourite_artist = Artist.objects.get(pk="foo")` the artist is returned, but `favourite_artist.pieces` throws an error stating `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pieces'`. I definitely have pieces as the related_name in my model.

Comment: That message tells you that you have a QuerySet instance, not an Artist instance. Double check how you're getting the object.

Comment: I made a couple changes and made some progress, but it's still not working. I removed `related_name='pieces'` from the model, also made `favourite_artist.pieces` singular, so it's now `favourite_artist.piece`, which I noticed is the way the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/) has it shown. However I'm now getting the error `'RelatedManager' object is not iterable`

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I think I might be misinterpreting how these searches work. I come from a CakePHP/Laravel background where a query for this would return both the Artist and the ArtistPiece in the same object. Ex: `{Artist : { 'name' : 'some_name'....}, 'ArtistPiece' : { 'piece_name' : 'name', ...}}`. Is that true for Django, or in this situation would it be standard practice to query `Artist` and set a variable, and then set a separate variable after querying `ArtistPiece`?

Answer (score 0):

`ArtistPiece.objects.filter(artist=artist_id)`, this will return a queryset.

If you want a list you can do `ArtistPiece.objects.filter(artist=artist_id).values_list('id', flat=True)`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Comment: Let me know if this is not what you wanted

Comment: the first query works, but it only returns the `ArtistPiece` entries for that artist_id, not both `Artist` and `ArtistPiece`. The second one returns the following error `'int' object has no attribute '_meta'`